# How to input a condition or a command from user in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, input, conditional-statements

Is there any way in python to input a condition from user? for example:

```
import numpy as np
m = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5])
condition = input() # for example 'm > 50'
print( m [condition])
```

I want a result of **m[m>5]** but I want to input this condition from user. Is there any way?

Comment: You can input numbers, string keys, but inputting variable names is a really bad and tricky practice. Can't your users directly use the python shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. You can do it using the built-in `eval()` function but **only if you can trust the input source**. If you cannot, the user can supply harmful input that can corrupt your system. `eval` is known to be potentially very dangerous. `eval` takes its string argument, parses it and evaluates it as a Python expression. This can be an arbitrary Python expression. One concern is that Python permits users to access and delete system files (e.g. via the `os` module). So a bad-actor may supply dangerous data that you feed into eval, which could corrupt your system. This is why you need to be extra careful that you can trust the input source before supplying it to eval.

If you know, for example, that the condition will always be something like `m ? x` where `?` is one of `<, <=, >=, ==, >`, then a safer approach is the following. You can first let the user input one of those options and check to make sure the user entered one of them. Then you can let the user enter the number `x`. You can then use `eval` to evaluate the concatenated string. For example,

```
import numpy as np

m = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5])

select = {'<', '<=', '>', '>=', '=='}

sym = input("Enter one of <, <=, >, >=, ==: ")
if sym not in select:
    print("Invalid input")
    exit()
num = float(input("Enter number: "))

condition = eval('m ' + sym + repr(num))
print(m[condition])
```

Example Session

```
Enter one of <, <=, >, >=, ==: >
Enter number: 3
[4 5]
```

Example Session

```
Enter one of <, <=, >, >=, ==: harmful_code
Invalid input
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do something similar with `eval`, I think:

```py
x = 5
condition = input('condition: ')
if eval(condition):
    print('yes')
```

And than in input write like `x==5` or `x>2` etc. and it should work.

Comment: @theherk I am very thankful to you, is there a way I can format code on this website with phone

Comment: You can, but entering special characters like `\`` can be annoying.

Comment: @PedramPorbaha please upvote my answer too

Comment: Keep in mind that using `eval` is a [**very bad practice**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice), in short **do not do this**. The other answer requires a bit more work and thinking but will be much more safe and robust (although not ideal as well).

Comment: @mozway ofcourse I agree with you that eval is pretty dangerous but I don't think he is using his console based project just for himself that is why I think he can use it although he can also demand the condition and do the needed programming ( like in your answer)

Comment: You can do much better than `eval` with simple code. If OP is using code for themself, why not using the shell directly? That justification makes no sense. Btw, I did **not** provide an answer ;)

Comment: @mozway sorry I thought it was your answer bur it was oda's answer sometimes specially when we are beginners we want to do things like this for ourselves and impressing our parents although ofcourse it is dangerous